# Fullcalendar mostrar hora e minutos

Tags: php, html, fullcalendar

O meu fullcalendar está exibindo a hora de eventos, só que por exemplo: 08:00(Quando é **:00) e quando é 08:30 ele mostra a hora com minutos.

Queria deixar ele mostrando as horas e minutos mesmo quando for 08:00 não só quando for 08:30

Comment: nao entendi, você pode explicar melhor com trecho do codigo? FullCalendar é aquela ferramenta em JS ??

Comment: Descreva mais a dúvida, problema. Melhor postar o código que faz o controle da exibição em php e o código em js que faz a interação com o documento html no navegador.

Comment: O problema é esse, não sei onde fica o trecho do código que faz essa visualização... baixei do site celke: https://celke.com.br/artigo/como-editar-um-evento-no-fullcalendar-com-janela-modal-do-bootstrap

Comment: Não estou a encontrar o que descreve, como assim `08:00(Quando é **:00) e quando é 08:30 ele mostra a hora com minutos.`?

Comment: Quando é uma hora certinha "08:00" ele mostra só 08, mas quando é hora com alguns minutos quebrados ele mostra inteiro "08:30".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só adicionar uma linha timeFormat no calendário:

`$('#calendario').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
                editable: false,
                eventLimit: false, 
                events: 'eventos.php',

                eventColor: '#dd6777'
                **timeFormat: 'H(:mm)'**
            });`

Answer (score 0):

Adicione ao seu `personalizado.css` dentro da pasta `/css` a reescrita da seguinte regra css:

```
.fc-time-grid-event.fc-short .fc-time:before {
   content: attr(data-full);
}
```

Essa classe define o comportamento do elemento quando existe um intervalo menor de 1 hora entre início e fim.  Basicamente ela atribui ao elemento before o valor do atributo `data-full` . A configuração padrão para esse elemento funciona de uma forma lógica. Porém apenas fazendo essa modificação você alcançará o resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso a V4 e testei os dois exemplos que colocaram e não funcionou, o que resolveu pra mim foi mexer diretamente no arquivo JS "daygrid/main.min.js" e alterar o trecho

**de**

```
n.prototype.computeEventTimeFormat=function(){
    return{
        hour:"numeric",
        minute:"2-digit",
        omitZeroMinute:!0,
        meridiem:"narrow"
    }
}
```

**para**

```
n.prototype.computeEventTimeFormat=function(){
    return{
        hour:"2-digit",
        minute:"2-digit",
        omitZeroMinute:0,
        meridiem:"narrow"
    }
}
```

A pergunta é um pouco antiga mais pode ajudar nas novas versões, achei a resposta no stack versão inglês.

Abraços.